# How to modify lc_swith button position when I press esc?

Tags: button, fullscreen, keyup

I have integrated lc_switch* button to my website to allow fullscreen mode.
*: https://github.com/LCweb-ita/LC-switch
The button and the function works perfectly but if I press "Esc" key to exit fullscreen mode the LC_switch button don't change position to "off".

https://codepen.io/Artenis/pen/xxOopyP

I have tried that with no result:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(event) {
          if(event.key === "Escape") {
            $('.lcs_label_on').css('left','-50px');
            $('.lcs_label_off').css('right','0px');
}
```

edit : I have tried all solutions on the below page
I got this function from here: [How to detect escape key press with pure JS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-pure-js-or-jquery), and I tried to change Escape to == 27.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to the solution from [mirage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856580/mirage) using window.resize function and lot of conditional.

[accessing-escape-key-when-mozilla-is-in-full-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982618/accessing-escape-key-when-mozilla-is-in-full-screen)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if (window.navigator.standalone || (document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !=null) || (document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen) || (!window.screenTop && !window.screenY)){
}else{
    $(".lcs_switch").removeClass("lcs_on").addClass("lcs_off");
}
});
```